# vba/API web scraping

Tags: excel, vba, api, web-scraping

I'm trying to extract values from a website in a loop. it's basically inputing the value in pressure and it outputs the temperature value. I have the full code and it is working but only when the loop is in n=n+1 but when I change the loop into n=n+0.1 (I'm trying to extract more data) the output is the same value every time even though a 0.1 on the website changes the output value and the excel code starts to crash after few seconds. could please tell me what might be the reason for this?

```
Option Explicit

Public Function GetPressureFromTemp(ByVal temperature As Double) As Double
    Dim body As String
  
    body = "{""temperature"":""" & temperature & """,""refId"":""r410a"",""temperatureUnit"":""fahrenheit"",""pressureUnit"":""psi"","
    body = body & """pressureReferencePoint"":""gauge"","
    body = body & """pressureCalculationPoint"":""bubble"",""gaugeType"":""dry"",""altitudeInMeter"":0}"
       
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", "https://reftools.danfoss.com/api/ref-slider/pressure?refId=r410a", False
        .setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        .send body
        GetPressureFromTemp = CDbl(.responseText)
    End With
End Function

Public Sub test()
Dim n As Integer
       
n = 20

Do Until n = 20.1
n = n + 0.1

Debug.Print GetPressureFromTemp(n)
  Loop
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Your n is an integer which won't have any decimal places.

Comment: Yes, change `Dim n As Integer` to `Dim n As Double`

Comment: thank you, the solution works but when I put n=20, do until n= 21, the Loop as = n+0.1. it starts to lag again and crash the excel file while it should only be printing out 10 values only

Comment: How often is the loop executed before crashing? Maybe better use `Do Until n >= 21`